# How can I confirm download status for yum update on RHEL5/CentOS5?

Tags: centos, rhel, yum

I have an older server/appliance running CentOS 5.x.  When I run updates on it, yum shows something like this:

[image: yum status]

The screen stays like that until all packages are downloaded -- no status or progress bar.  Is there a way I can see how far along a download is? Some sort of confirmation that yum is still retrieving the contents?

Comment: If you add the `-d 2` (or higher) option to `yum`, does it show the package names and progress bars?

Comment: What is the output of `grep debuglevel /etc/yum.conf` ?